# How to grep in one line starting from particular string to end with particular string

Tags: grep

**I want to grep "[calleruid]=aab01b055-89e3-49f3-839e-507bb128d07e&smscresponse"
in Below file**

```
2014-10-15 18:38:32,831 plivo-rest[2781]: INFO: Fetching GET http://*******/outbound_callback.aspx with smscresponse[to]=8912722fsf9&smscresponse[ALegUUID]=5bb516fsd64-546c-11e4-879f-551816a551303677&smscresponse[calluid]=aab01b055-89e3-49f3-839e-507bb128d07e&smscresponse[direction]=outbosund&smscresfdsponse[endreason]=UNALLOCATED_NUMBER&smscresponse[from]=83339995896999&smscresponse[starttime]=0&smscresponse[ALegRequestUUID]=5bb4bafc-546c-11e4-891d-000c29ec6e41&smscresponse[RequestUUID]=5bb4bafc-546c-11e4-891d-000c29ec6e41&smscresponse[callstatus]=completed&smscresponse[endtime]=1413378509&smscresponse[ScheduledHangupId]=5bb4c15a-546c-11e4-891d-000c29ec6e41&smscresponse[event]=missed_call_hangup
```

I used this command

```
$ grep -oP '(calluid).*$'
```

this greps upto end of file

I used this command

```
$ grep -oP '(calluid).{40}'
```

it fetches 40 characters but i have 1000's of calleruid's so each have different no.s of characters

So please guide me to grep exact callerid data

Comment: did the input contains new line characters?

Comment: no total in sing;le line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a lookahead to force the regex engine to do the match upto a specific character or a boundary.

```
$ grep -oP '\[calluid\][^\]\[]*(?=\[|$)' file
[calluid]=aab01b055-89e3-49f3-839e-507bb128d07e&smscresponse
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an `gnu awk` (due to multiple characters in RS) version:

```
awk -v RS="[[]calluid[]]=" -F[ 'NR==2 {print $1}' file
aab01b055-89e3-49f3-839e-507bb128d07e&smscresponse
```

You can also set RS like this: `RS="\\\[calluid]="`